Declare custom $_SERVER variable
I am setting $_SERVER variables in an include file as follows -
$_SERVER['BOT'] = isset($_SERVER['BOT']) ? $_SERVER['BOT'] : 0; // assume this is not a bot
$_SERVER['REALPAGE'] = isset($_SERVER['REALPAGE']) ? $_SERVER['REALPAGE'] : 0; // assume this is a real page
if (!isset($_SERVER['HOST'])) {
  $_SERVER['HOST'] = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] : gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}
if (!isset($_SERVER['REFERER'])) {
  $_SERVER['REFERER'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "";
}
if (!isset($_SERVER['AGENT'])) {
  $_SERVER['AGENT'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : "";
}

These are then used in various other includes to define whether a page is real or the visitor IP address is a BOT.
Now what I have noticed is that whilst there are no problems with $_SERVER['BOT'], $_SERVER['REALPAGE'], $_SERVER['HOST'] and $_SERVER['REFERER'], sometimes $_SERVER['AGENT'] changes.
Is it because AGENT is a reserved word or something similar?
BTW I have no problems setting these even though research here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere on the web says it is not allowed.
Is there a reason I have no trouble setting these?

At first view, much better use a custom var, let's say $server, instead of the superglobal $_SERVER. You can initialize $server = $_SERVER; if needed.

"research here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere on the web says it is not allowed." - For what it's worth, $_SERVER is not and has never been read-only, and very popular packages like symfony/dotenv can write into it. Even if AGENT already exists (e.g. there is an env variable with that name), you can still overwrite it.

Ahh, so I might be better off using say $serverBOT. Meaning it's not a superglobal but retains it's value whilst processing the code relevant to the page requested. Thanks. Most helpful.

php.net documentation
$_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server, therefore there is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. However, most of these variables are accounted for in the » CGI/1.1 specification, and are likely to be defined.
Note: When running PHP on the command line most of these entries will not be available or have any meaning.

These are then used in various other includes to define whether a page
is real or the visitor IP address is a BOT.

there is no usefull reason for put a var inside $_SERVER since it is reset by the web server every time you reload the page.
so $AGENT='xxx' and $_SERVER['AGENT']='xxx' have the same lifecycle
the downside is that if your webserver use 'AGENT' (or any other key you try to override) as entry,
you may have some sideffect.

BTW I have no problems setting these even though research here on
Stackoverflow and elsewhere on the web says it is not allowed. Is
there a reason I have no trouble setting these?

you cannot change the super global value, what you did is "change the local value" at "page scope"
if you open another page or reload (the value of $_SERVER's entries is still the original one)

"there is no useful reason for put a var inside $_SERVER since it is reset by the web server every time you reload the page. so $AGENT='xxx' and $_SERVER['AGENT']='xxx' have the same lifecycle".
AHA, that helps a great deal because I never really understood how variables retain their values across code.
What I do is have a master page and then include various code elements that are on separate files. Sort of like you used to do in the old days with subroutines. Yes my coding experience goes back to the 1970's and 80's. Thank you.

That may also explain my problem as I also had the variable $agent in the code. Thanks for the suggestion.

Use ?= operator:
$_SERVER['BOT'] ?= 0; // if not set, set it to 0

You can use ?? operator too:
$_SERVER['AGENT'] ?= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? ""; // ... and if none set, set it to ""

The complete code:
$_SERVER['BOT'] ?= 0;

$_SERVER['REALPAGE'] ?= 0;

$_SERVER['HOST'] ?= $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?? gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$_SERVER['REFERER'] ?= $_SERVER['REFERER'] ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?? "";

$_SERVER['AGENT'] ?= $_SERVER['AGENT'] ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? "";

Also you can read values with out changing $_SERVER values (if it's acceptable in your code):
$bot = $_SERVER['BOT'] ?? 0;

$page = $_SERVER['REALPAGE'] ?? 0;

$host = $_SERVER['HOST'] ?? $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?? gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$ref = $_SERVER['REFERER'] ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?? "";

$agent = $_SERVER['AGENT'] ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? "";


Custom $_SERVER variable
$_SERVER['AGENT'] = 'MyValue';

Use the custom variable
echo $_SERVER['AGENT'];


The question asks about a specific problem with an 'AGENT' server variable. Not how to access such variables in general.
